# Clojure fn support for keyword or path argument for get-in

Tags: clojure, keyword

What is a clean way in Clojure to support a function argument that can be a keyword like `:name` or a path like `[:person :name]`, so that it can be used in a call to `get` or `get-in`?

Right now I have `(get-in m (flatten [path]))` where `path` is input. This works, but seems like it could get slow for frequent use, or in large collections of data - I have not benchmarked.

Alternatively, I guess I could dispatch on `(coll? path)` to use `get` or `get-in`:

```
(let [path [:person :name]
      m {:person {:name "John Smith"}}]
  (if (coll? path)
    (get-in m path) 
    (get m path)))
=> {:name "John Smith"}
```

Seems like it might be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the caller to be able to pass in either a keyword *or* a sequence of keywords, that's a perfectly legitimate way of doing it. I would probably use `keyword?` as the test instead of `coll?`, though, to make it a bit clearer; `coll?` would give some false positives (e.g. when the input is a map instead of a vector or sequence), but `keyword?` would not.

```
(let [m {:person {:name "John Smith"}}]
      path [:person :name]
  (if (keyword? path)
    (get m path)
    (get-in m path)))
;=> "John Smith"
```

Another way could be to treat the input as simply a function, which would allow you to avoid the conditional altogether:

```
(let [m {:person {:name "John Smith"}}
      f (comp :name :person)]
  (f m))
;=> "John Smith"
```

This isn't quite as nice as just keywords or sequences of keywords, though, and it allowing the caller to pass in an arbitrary function just to reach into a map could potentially cause problems.

Probably the best option in this case, though, would be to force the user to pass in a sequence and always use `get-in`. That would avoid the complexity of this sort of conditional, and also allow for more general maps. Consider this example:

```
(let [m {[:foo :bar] "John Smith"
         :foo {:bar "John Cena"}}
      path [:foo :bar]]
  (if (coll? path)
    (get-in m path)
    (get m path)))
;=> "John Cena"
```

In this case, the `path` is completely ambiguous; there's simply no way to determine what the caller *really* wanted. If all the keys in your maps are keywords, that's perfectly fine; you won't need to deal with this problem. But this just goes to show that adding implicit conversions can potentially allow you to shoot yourself in the foot later.

Comment: Good point about the ambiguity. Another option would be to support korks, e.g. `(my-fn :some :path)` that get parsed as `[& path]`, which supports both `(my-fn [:foo :bar])` and `(my-fn :foo :bar)`.

Comment: @pate Yep, if you can use variadic arguments, by all means do so. It's basically just syntactic sugar for passing in a sequence, though, which is why it doesn't have any ambiguity here.

Comment: It's different because you could do `(my-fn [:foo :bar] :more :bars)` which would result in `(get-in m [[:foo :bar] :more :bars])`, no?

Comment: @pate The term "syntactic sugar" isn't really correct in this case; I apologize for that. What I meant was that, in general, there's no practical difference between `((fn [args] args) [[:foo :bar] :baz :qux])` and `((fn [& args] args) [:foo :bar] :baz :qux)`. You can unambiguously pass in the same stuff either way; the only difference is what the calling code looks like.